# FullCalendar Drag and Drop not adding to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I am implementing FullCalendar onto my MVC web application and have the basic calendar working. I am now attempting to add adding external events which i have working apart from when the first event is first dragged on, it isnt added into the database. if the event is moved or edited it however is entered.

Is there a way to make the event entered directly into the database when initially dragged in?

This is my current code for adding external events.

```
addExternalEvent: true,
eventDrop: function (event) {
    var data = {
        EventID: event.eventID,
        Subject: event.title,
        Start: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
        End: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
        Description: event.description,
        ThemeColor: event.color,
        IsFullDay: event.allDay,
    };
    SaveEvent(data);
}

$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {
    $(this).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()), 
        stick: true 
    });

    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance.